# Websphere cxf spring issue for NamespaceHandler class

Tags: spring, cxf, websphere-8

I am getting the below exception while starting the application context in websphere.

I have deployed my war on Websphere 8.5.5 with class loading as parent last.

```
000000db ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/service-gateway-client-services.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
                at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:599)
                at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:743)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:720)
                at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
```

Comment: Which are your cxf libraries in classpath?

Comment: Following are the jars in my classpath

cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.1.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.1.jar
cxf-rt-rs-client-3.0.1.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.1.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.1.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.1.jar
cxf-core-3.0.1.jar

Comment: `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler` class is at file cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs and `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport` at spring-beans.jar. Ensure that they are loaded in your app

Comment: Both the jars are already present in my WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Could you post the main parts of your xml file?